# How to reset the recyclerview become into its original state (EMPTY)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to do a RESET button. I already successfully do for Spinner and Seekbar but failed to do for RecyclerView which is my filtering result. There is no error, but as you can see in my output interface, ONLY the recyclerView did not empty...

My coding:-

```
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FilterTuitionCentre.this, R.raw.soundeffect1);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();

            spLocation.setSelection(0);
            seekbarPrice.setProgress(0);
            spAcademicLevel.setSelection(0);
            spSubject.setSelection(0);
            recyclerView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

My interface output:-

[image]

My adapter coding:-

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: If you are trying to clear all items from the RecyclerView, you need to delete all items from its adapter and then notify it via an appropriate method. If you are trying to only remove whatever filter applied on it, in order to show all items, then it will depend on how results are being filtered. `invalidate` only forces a redraw of the View, it does not empty it.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Alright sir, then how to empty it? Do you have any coding example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you have following initialization for your recyclerView :

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(items);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To clear items(Empty) RecyclerView you need to :

```
items.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: how is your adapter look like?

Comment: Clear List<item> that you pass to it and notifyDataSetChange() to empty your recyclerView, instead of invalidate()